# Creating attribute tables and joining tables

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-table, attribute-joins, excel

I hope someone can help me! So I have multiple shapefiles and layers. I didn't give them an ID when I created them. But now that I have finished my drawings, I need to give them an id (?) and I need to join an excel table where I have all the information for each layer (more than hundred), so people can look for different attributes. So I have to give an id one by one? And what step should I do next so I can join tables? I've been looking for it but all the examples only have one layer, and I need to know how to do that for multiple layers.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some general steps:

1. Add all shapefiles into Q, open their attribute tables, start an edit session, create the ID fields, populate with unique values (that match related records in your Excel file(s)), and save edits
2. Export each Excel sheet that relates to a single layer to individual .csv files
3. Add the .csv into Q as a delimited text layer
4. Finally, on the related shapefile, right click layer name in the layer panel select Properties and select the Join tab to set the join

Repeat step 4 above for all related .csv files and shapefiles.